# Google Pay Production Environment

Tags: google-play-console, google-pay, android-app-signing

I am trying to integrate Google Pay into my app and so far it's been working great on the test environment, when i started the process to enable on the production environment with the Google Pay team, they confirmed that i have enabled the environment from their side and from the merchant side on the play console account, still i keep getting "Request Failed, this merchant is not enabled for Google Pay" dialog whenever i click on the GPay button.

After a long Email thread with the google pay team they told me to contact the play console team as there could be an issue with my app signing since i keep getting the 405 error.

I did contact the Play Console support team and since i originally had opted in the "let Google handle your app signing" they asked that i use up my one time per app lifetime of requesting changing the upload certificate to change to a new keystore and send them both the keystore and .pem certificate, now that this change has been made and now i am trying to test again and i keep getting the same error again.

I have no clue what to do with such thing and both Google support teams cannot offer me any beneficial info anymore.

Comment: I'm now in the testing step, but I got the google pay screen with no total price or items in it's view is this normal in testing or I missing something to display total price in google pay?

Comment: I also faced same issue @Neo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved by 2 steps

1- Had to make sure the app signing certificate that google was providing matched the one i had.

2- There was also a problem with enabling Google Pay on production from Google's side which they enabled after continuing debugging with their team from the same email thread that started with the enable production environment request.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are enrolled in *App Signing by Google Play* and it looks like you have configured GPay to work with your app signed with your **upload key** (and/or debug key) but not with your **app signing key**, which is what Play serves to end-users.

Ensure that you **also whitelist the SHA1 of your app signing key**.

You can find it in the **App signing page** of the Play Console under "Release management":

[image: Screenshot of App Size page]

Comment: what do u mean by whitelist the SHA1 of my app signing key? the entire fingerprints of the app signing certificates are managed by Google and not me

Comment: Google keeps the app signing private key secure but still shows you the fingerprint of the associated certificate (see screenshot). Similarly to how you've already whitelisted the SHA1 of the key inside your keystore in Google Pay API console, you also need to whitelist the SHA1 of the app signing certificate displayed in the Play Console.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Didn't you already whitelist a sha1 with your package name in the Google Cloud Console?

Comment: i am using google pay to connect to a payment gateway, in my case it's authorize.net

Comment: never even thought about doing anything with google cloud console

Comment: @Pierre, How we whitelist a SHA1 with package name in Google Cloud Console? A screenshot or link to that part is much appreciated. Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Totalprice and display items not showing in Google pay sheet. Thanks in advance.