# Issue in production mode of Google Pay android

Tags: android, production-environment, google-pay

In Test Environment of Google Pay, I can able to get token, but when I make my **shop as Production and making Google Pay as a Production environment**, I am getting a 405 error code saying "**This merchant is not enabled for Google Pay**". I have already enabled Google Pay inside the Accelerated Checkouts section.

From the error code, I found that I have to verify the SHA1 key with the Google Play console as [mentioned here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/test-and-deploy/deploy-your-application#sign-your-app-with-release-keys). I have also checked the SHA1 key via given keytool with the release apk and both SHA1 keys are the same. Still, I am getting 405 error code.

Also, Someone on Stackoverflow, [mentioned that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60992220/5917224) I have to whitelist my SHA1 key inside the Google Play Console, but there is no any fields inside the Google Play Console where I could whitelist my SHA1 key.

***Note:*** I have uploaded my apk on play store and from there I am getting the 405 error code.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because support questions regarding the Google Play Console/Google Pay should be asked in the relevant support forums or by contacting customer support. (See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165 for more information.)

Comment: @Rushabh, please use the *Contact Support* option at http://pay.google.com/business/console. It would be great if you could answer this question if support is able to help you out so that others may benefit.

Comment: I have tried that option, but they are saying to use Contact Support option at https://support.google.com/googleplay/gethelp. I have emailed them my issue, but didn't received any response by them. (They are saying to reply back in 24 hrs and right now It is not over), So still waiting for reply from them.